# Shopify , show product options as 3 seperate dropdowns instead of 1 single dropdown

Tags: shopify, variant

On my product page, with the following line of code in the product.liquid template, it generates 3 seperate dropdowns for the 3 different product options the product has, eg Type Color Size..

```
  <div class="select">
    <select id="product-select" name="id">
      {% for variant in product.variants %}
      <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
```

however, i used the same code in the product-loop.liquid to show the same drop down on the collections page (without the option to add to cart).. but this time the dropdown appears as 1 single combined dropdown.

how do i split them up like before?

heres a screenshot of what both dropdowns look like :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `option_selection.js` in your collection.liquid template.
paste the following line at top or bottom of your `collection.liquid` template

```
{{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
```

Comment: hmm thats strange, i dont have option_selection.js in my asset. maybe its my theme. (using the default launchpad).

Comment: ok i found out its a global asset. and so i tried adding the line to the bottom of the collection template im using. doesnt work. i also tried adding it to the start of the collection template, <head> of the theme.liquid and just before the closing of <body> in theme.liquid